# When should the session ID be regenerated?

Tags: php, security

I know it is good practice to use session_regenerate_id(). I've heard some people that say it should be used extensively, and others that say it should just be used on login/logout. Is there any justification to the latter? Is running the function an expensive process that should be avoided when it is not really necessary?

**Edit**: More than anything, I really want to know the justification for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Session ID should be regenerated after login ,logout or get administrative access . this [Regenerate PHP session id](http://www.xqus.com/regenerate-php-session-id) also helpful

Comment: Yes, but what is the reason to not place it on every single PHP page?